# Different dropDownListViewStyles for different spinner styles

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-theme, android-styles

In my application theme I have `dropDownListViewStyle` and `spinnerStyle` for whole application. But in one fragment I need spinner with custom styled `dropDownListViewStyle` (I need to change divider). Is it possible to have spinner with other `dropDownListViewStyle` then is set in theme?

In spinner style or layout is not possible to set dropdown divider. Also is not possible to set dropDownListViewStyle in spinner style or layout.

I am really stucked, hope someone have the answer.

Comment: Is this Spinner in an Activity with other spinners?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Activity contains more fragments (some of them contains spinners) and one fragment contains this special styled spinner.

Comment: Will you be awarding this bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `dropDownListViewStyle` is hardcoded in `Spinner`. If you look into the source, you'll find the `DropdownPopup` class, which extends `ListPopupWindow`. In `ListPopupWindow` the class of interest is `DropDownListView` where you'll find the constructor:

```
public DropDownListView(Context context, boolean hijackFocus) {
    super(context, null, com.android.internal.R.attr.dropDownListViewStyle);
    // ...
}
```

So the only way to change this is by theme, as you've assessed. Considering that the `Spinner` in question is being used in an `Activity` that requires the base theme, I know of only one workaround. Unfortunately, the only way to do it is to change the theme of the `Fragment`. This means that *all* `Spinners` in that `Fragment` will have the alternative theme. To change the theme of your `Fragment` at runtime, in your `onCreateView` do this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
        Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.My_Custom_Theme);
        // clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
        LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(context);
        // inflate using the cloned inflater, not the passed in default 
        return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    }
```

Short of this, you're looking at creating a custom `Spinner`, which isn't *too* difficult, considering that it's open source.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! You just confirmed what I thought. I just hoped I'm still overlooking something because it's weird, that it's not possible to achieve this using styles/themes.

Comment: Glad to help. Now about that bounty... ;-)